# SSIS - Archive files Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I am developing SSIS 2008 package.
Amongst other things, it processes files located in a drop-off filesystem folder.

**TASK:**

After they are processed, files should be compressed and relocated to an archive folder.

**QUESTION(s):**

Does anyone know of a better solution, then to use an "Execute Process Task", calling a batch file which calls a 7-zip packer?
Any freeware custom tasks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better in what way? IMHO that is the best solution.

Comment: I think Script task i the best way for Zip and Archive. You will get more flexibility and control over it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4cdc3661-f75f-4857-8909-0ca366c63caa/ssis-zip-files?forum=sqlintegrationservices) is an answer to your question. You may have to make sure about the .net framework that you are using and whether it supports gzip or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to zip the file by using script task

http://forums.asp.net/p/1086292/1743179.aspx